# Как использовать Sqlite в AsyncTask классе

Tags: java, android, sqlite, асинхронность

В чатсности я хотел бы использовать insert в фоновом режиме то есть:

```
class SyncMails extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
   // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute(){
        GetWebLinks();
        adapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>)listViewEmails.getAdapter();
    }




    protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        dbHelper.insertQuestion(e_mail);
        publishProgress( String.valueOf(listEmails.add("Searching started ... ")));
```

И на выходе получаю ошибки:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: questions.question (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE[2067])
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:995)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:2021)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1890)
    at web.email.gettersetter.DbHelper.insertQuestion(DbHelper.java:113)
```

Ошибка выдается из:

```
return db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT1,null,values);
```

Comment: [Первая же ссылка в гугле](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415469)

Comment: У меня другой случай, а именно проблема внутри класса Async, вне этого класса работает без проблем

Comment: покажите код `insertQuestion()`

Comment: {    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

String Query_Table1=" CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_STUDENT1+ "("
+KEY_ID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
+QUESTIONS+ " TEXT UNIQUE)";
db.execSQL(Query_Table1);



}

public long insertQuestion(String question1) {
db=this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(QUESTIONS,question1);


return db.insert(TABLE_STUDENT1,null,values);
}
}

Comment: судя по описанию ошибки ты пытаешься вставить повторяющееся значение в столбец с ограничением. может быть твой код и рабочий и дело не в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Решение - установил insert перед циклом for и заработало!
Кажется не успевает внутри цикла for, не хотел я писать дополнительный код, но видимо придется.